# How to use telnet client in Ubuntu 18.04 terminal?

Tags: command-line, telnet

I read book about programming and networks.. Found this example:

[image]

As written in this book, after last `<Enter>` we must receive page raw HTML code..

I upload small script to my host to minimize amount of HTML code (script just print client IP) and try get this script in telnet interface:

```
$ telnet sflash.biz 80
Trying 109.206.168.84...
Connected to sflash.biz.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I found in askubuntu answers '**^]**' is same <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>. Push it and try type next line with GET request of my script URI, but telnet return this error **?Invalid command**:

```
^[^]
telnet> GET /ip.php HTTP/1.1
?Invalid command
telnet>
```

Is something custom with **Ubuntu telnet** or I do something wrong?

Comment: Do _not_ press the escape character. Just type in what's shown in the book. (By the way, `^]` is Ctrl + ], no need for Alt.)

Answer (score 3):

try this:
$ telnet sflash.biz 80
Trying 109.206.168.84...
Connected to sflash.biz.
Escape character is '^]'
GET /ip.php HTTP/1.1
Host: sflash.biz

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> makes the `^]` and then gives you the telnet prompt where you can type "quit".

Comment: CTRL + 5 to be exact no need to include shift key